# Output Wordpress page/post title as HTTP header in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I'm attempting to add a custom HTTP header to my Wordpress site where it calls the page or posts title as the result. The code below (placed in functions.php) succesfully outputs the header name but I'm not sure how to get the post/page title:

```
function add_header_title($headers) {

if (!is_admin()) {
  $headers['X-IC-Title'] = wp_title();
}
return $headers;
}
add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_header_title');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the function [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) as described in the codex

Comment: ` function add_header_title($headers) {
  global $post;
  $title = get_the_title($post);

    if (!is_admin()) {
      $headers['X-IC-Title'] = $title;
    }
    return $headers;
 }
 add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_header_title');`

Comment: `function add_header_title($headers) {
  global $post;
  $title = get_the_title($post);

    if (!is_admin()) {
      $headers['X-IC-Title'] = $title;
    }
    return $headers;
 }
add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_header_title');`